# not able to download from ftp (anonymous server) ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp, afnetworking

How to dowload zip file from anonymous ftp server from AFNetworking ? (`ftp://167.114.2.188/Quran/zipfiles/Alafasy/2.zip`)

Answer (score -1):

just copy paste your url into a browser or ftp-client: in case of this file it seems the server is overly busy, i get a timeout error on it. A good every purpose ftp-client is Filezilla from https://filezilla-project.org, it is open-source and free and always up to date and same for windows, linux, mac.